# Monitor resolution problem (nouveau-driver, 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04.1)

Tags: resolution, xrandr, nouveau

All of a sudden the system changed the screen resolution to 1240x768. I have an AOC 931 Swl with optimal resolution: 1366x768 (60 Hz).

outputs:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

and

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
```

did then

```
cvt 1366x768 60
# 1368x60 50.19 Hz (CVT) hsync: 3.81 kHz; pclk: 6.50 MHz
Modeline "1368x60_60.00"    6.50  1368 1408 1536 1704  60 63 73 76 -hsync +vsync // I wonder why Modeline shows ...x60 instead of ...x768?
```

I tried to apply this using

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x60_60.00"    6.50  1368 1408 1536 1704  60 63 73 76 -hsync +vsync //ok, no error msg
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1366x768 // msg: xrandr: cannot find mode "1368x768"
```

Does somebody have an idea, how I can (re)set to right resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement has to match the --newmode statement:
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1368x60_60.00

Though I've never used a mode name with a .00 before. Usually the name would be 1366x768_60.

Comment: Problem solved. I tried with the NVidia binary X.Org driver ('version 173' driver) restarted but it got worse (recognized as Laptop 640x480). So I uninstalled that driver, restart and - by some unknown magic - I have the right resolution back! :)